# SQL single Quote(test'S)using sql

Tags: sql

how to insert single column using sql insert query
insert into table value(test's);

Comment: `insert into my_table (my_column) values (123);`?

Comment: `insert into the_table (the_column) values (42);`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Should have used 42 in my comment.

Comment: Do you want to insert a new row, or a new column? (What have you got, and what do you want?)

Comment: @jarlh From my understanding. OP wants to insert a string with an apostrophe

Comment: @JamesS, I see. (The question has been edited since I read it.)

Comment: `insert into table values ('test''s');`. i.e. double the single quote inside the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the column name

Let's assume the table has 3 columns c1, c2, and c2

```sql
INSERT INTO myTable (c1)
VALUES ('c1v1'), 
       ('c1v2')
```

OR

```sql
INSERT INTO myTable (c1)
SELECT 'c1v1' UNION 
SELECT 'c1v2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting to INSERT a value with an apostrophe, you need to use an escape:

```
INSERT INTO table
VALUES
('test''s')
```

Answer (score 0):

are you asking about inserting a column? if yes then

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```

else read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-insert-statement/) article about inserting into columns, it will help. it is very detailed